# Consulta MYSQL no devuelve nada aunque hay datos

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.6

tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql configurado en una vps en linux. Resulta que en localhost esto me funciona, pero en la vps no trabaja, me devuelve que no hay productos.

```
            if(!empty($_POST['buscar'])){
                $buscar=limpiar($_POST['buscar']);
                $poa=mysql_query("SELECT producto.codigo FROM producto, contenido 
                WHERE contenido.deposito='$id_bodega' and (producto.codigo='$buscar' or producto.nombre='$buscar') GROUP BY producto.nombre");  
                if($roow=mysql_fetch_array($poa)){
                    $codigo=$roow['codigo'];
                    $pa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM caja_tmp WHERE producto='$codigo' and usu='$usu' and ref=''");   
                    if($row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)){
                        $cant=$row['cant']+1;
                        mysql_query("UPDATE caja_tmp SET cant='$cant' WHERE producto='$codigo' and usu='$usu'");
                    }else{
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO caja_tmp (producto, cant, usu) VALUES ('$codigo','1','$usu')");    
                    }
                }else{
                    echo mensajes('El Producto que busca no se encuentra Registrado en la Base de Datos','rojo');   
                }
            }
```

Comment: Estas realizando bien la conexion al servidor?

Comment: Si, la conexión al servidor está correctamente. De hecho funciona el software, pero no hace consultas de ese tipo.